# Swift command center playback control throwing exception

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make audio playback controllable from the command center. The audio is being played from a view that has a new instance created every time a segue is triggered from the file list when a file is selected for playing.

The code that configures the command center controls is present in the `viewDidLoad` function of the player view:

```
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance();
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback);
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true);
        } catch {}

        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents();

        TableViewController.commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared();

        TableViewController.commandCenter!.togglePlayPauseCommand.isEnabled = true;
        TableViewController.commandCenter!.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.playbacker!.TogglePlayPause))
```

The first time I am entering the player view, the control center commands work perfectly fine. The problem arises when I am selecting another file for playback and the view is recreated. Then I am presented with the following exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_MPWeakInvocationTarget
>   TogglePlayPause]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170032340'

I have tried making the `MPRemoteCommandCenter` variable static, the player view reference static, but the results are the same.

Could anybody please give me some indication on why is this not working?

Comment: I have also same issue. did you resolved this?

Comment: I haven't touched that code since January, but if I read the commit correctly, I moved the definitions specific to the command center to the `application`function of `AppDelegate.swift`. I made the first lines of the function be `UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents();` and `commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared();` and then continued with enabling the buttons of the `commandCenter` variable.

Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: I have added first line   UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents(); In AppDelegate.swift  still giving same error. Please check this 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711137/mpweakinvocationtarget-pause-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance'