# [_MPWeakInvocationTarget pause]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

In PlayerAndLyricsViewController i have added

```
 class PlayerAndLyricsViewController: UIViewController{

  let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

  override func viewDidLoad() {

         commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, 
                action:#selector(nextPressed))
         commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
    }
   @IBAction func nextPressed(_ sender: Any) {
       // Some code
   }

}
```

I am using commandCenter to enable and disable for next, back and pause button.

When I initialise PlayerAndLyricsViewController first time Control Center working fine (Next, Pervious, Pause button), then I
pop the controller from navigation stack and again initialising this controller from other view controller . Now i am putting application in background and clicking on next button (Control center) or previous button throwing error(Crash)

> [_MPWeakInvocationTarget pause]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

or

> [_MPWeakInvocationTarget nextPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

I am not getting whats going wrong. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: `[_MPWeakInvocationTarget nextPressed]` So the signature of the method is `func nextPressed()`, with no parameter (that's not the method you wrote), and you did `#selector(nextPressed)`, you didn't put the correct selector.

Comment: Actually i tried with normal function as well still giving same issue. If this is an issue as you said then it should throw error every time but it is not. First time working fine but second time get crashed.

Comment: Try `action:#selector(PlayerAndLyricsViewController.nextPressed(_:))` instead? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673261/classname-has-no-member-functionname-when-adding-uibutton-target

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["classname has no member functionname" when adding UIButton target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673261/classname-has-no-member-functionname-when-adding-uibutton-target)

Comment: Tried with 'action:#selector(PlayerAndLyricsViewController.nextPressed(_‌​:)) ' this as well. Still  Same issue.

Comment: And then what's the error message when you tap nextPressed?

Comment: [_MPWeakInvocationTarget nextPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Finally got solution. I have to remove target in view did disapper. commandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget(self)
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.removeTarget(self)